# Como passo para tela um objeto serializado?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Estou tentando converte um objeto que contem um relacionamento e serializando afim, de envia-lo para View por `Ajax`. Tenho duas classes relacionadas

```
public class Eventos : IEntidade<EventosAuditoria>
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Guid ProfissionalId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Nome não pode ser em branco!")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maximo de 30 caracteres!")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public String HoraEvento { get; set; }
    //public String DuracaoEvento { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }

    public bool Consulta { get; set; }

    public bool Retorno { get; set; }

    public String Observacoes { get; set; }

    //relacionamento com tabela profissional
    public virtual Profissional Profissional { get; set; }
}
```

E minha classe Profissional

```
[Table("Profissional")]
public class Profissional : IEntidade<ProfissionalAuditoria>
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProfissionalId { get; set; }

    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    //Relacionamento com tabela eventos
    public virtual ICollection<Eventos> Eventos { get; set; }
}
```

Porém ao tentar informar o valor de ProfissionalId na tela, da seguinte forma:

```
public JsonResult ObtemPorId(int id)
{
    var evento = Db.Eventos.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
    return Json(evento, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Ele vem como 00000-0000-0000... Então buscando algumas formas de resolver, vi que com a biblioteca `Json.net` é possível. Mas, tive alguns problemas na implementação. Segue-os abaixo.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
   $.ajax({
   url: '/Home/ObtemPorId',
   Type: 'POST',
   data: $('#ID').val(calEvent.ID),
   success: function(response) {
      $('#editEventTitle').val(response.title);
      $('#editEventDate').val(response.start);
      $('#editEventTime').val(response.end);
      ModalAdicionar(response)//Aqui passo o os dados recebidos para o modal
     }
});

function ModalAdicionar(date) {
            ClearPopupFormValues();
            $('#ModalAdicionar').modal('show');
            $('#eventTitle').focus();
        }
```

e em meu controller, tento devolver os dados *serializados*

```
public JsonResult ObtemPorId(int id)
{
    var evento = Db.Eventos.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(evento, Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Porém, o resultado que chega pra mim no *Response* é algo parecido com isso

```
"Profissional": {
 "Eventos": [
 {
     "ID": 3,

     "ProfissionalId": "47961ca9-4a6e-451b-b984-2123134587fa",

     "title": "Renan Carlos",

    "start": "2017-05-31T12:00:00",
     "HoraEvento": null,
     "end": "2017-05-31T12:30:00",
     "Consulta": false,
     "Retorno": false,
     "Observacoes": null,
     "DataCriacao": "2017-05-30T15:14:37.053",
     "UsuarioCriacao": "renancp91@gmail.com",
     "UltimaModificacao": null,
     "UsuarioModificacao": null
   },
   {
     "ID": 4,
     "ProfissionalId": "47961ca9-4a6e-451b-b984-2123134587fa",
     "title": "Renan",
     "start": "2017-05-31T11:30:00",
     "HoraEvento": null,
     "end": "2017-05-31T12:00:00",
     "Consulta": false,
     "Retorno": false,
     "Observacoes": null,
     "DataCriacao": "2017-05-30T15:32:08.897",
     "UsuarioCriacao": "renancp91@gmail.com",
     "UltimaModificacao": null,
     "UsuarioModificacao": null ...
```

Que é algo, bem diferente do esperado. E mudando esta linha

```
new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
```

Para:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize});
```

Tenho essa mensagem:

> 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Eventos_E1047ACBD21CEA4B87C1021CE8FEFEDFE86C5AC747E6D7FF7170ADD1A1872419'.

Como posso fazer está implementação ? 
Ps: Preciso passar a informação de ProfissionalId, contida em Eventos.

Comment: Se você precisa somente do *ProfissionalId*, poderia simplesmente usar `return Content(evento.ProfissionalId.ToString());`

Comment: @RicardoPontual me expressei mal, fiz a edição

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult ObtemPorId(int id)
{
    var evento = Db.Eventos.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Testa só isto, penso que deveria funcionar.

Comment: Dessa forma não funciona. Editei a pergunta inserindo mais detalhes e explicando o que já tentei e porque não funcionou.

Comment: podes explicar melhor o que nao funciona? e tu queres devolver o objecto Evento certo?

Comment: isto é.. da algum erro?

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar o atributo abaixo nas classes que deseja serializar:

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class Eventos : IEntidade<EventosAuditoria>
{
...
}
```

e

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
[Table("Profissional")]
public class Profissional : IEntidade<ProfissionalAuditoria>
{
...
}
```

Comment: Com isso eu utilizo eu não preciso dos métodos do Json.Net no controller ?

Comment: Gosto de utilizar a biblioteca Newtonsoft.Json que você pode obter via Nuget.Na API o apenas retorno como  `return Json(MyObject)`

Comment: Estou usando ela.